# Searching for column != values weirdly excludes NULL values in my queries

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a query in Marketing Cloud which searches for records in my `Contact_Salesforce` DE.
I have a condition where it excludes records if the values are within a certain range, what I've noticed is it will exclude those records but also exclude any records with `NULL` values even though it's not been explicitly added to the `WHERE` condition.

Here is what my query looks like

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Email, c.FirstName as FirstName, c.LastName as LastName
from Contact_Salesforce c
JOIN Account_Salesforce a ON a.Id = c.AccountId
WHERE ((a.Type <> 'Intern'
AND a.Type <> 'Contractor'
AND a.Type <> 'School Intern'
AND a.Type <> 'Internal User')
OR a.Type IS NULL)
```

You can see the only way I've found around this is by creating a rule set and explicitly looking for records where `Type IS NULL`.

Can anyone explain why the query doesn't include null values if I don't add `a.Type IS NULL`?

Comment: Where's the rest of your query?

Comment: Apologies, I stripped out some of the conditions there were unrelated to simplify the query for the post. I have corrected the query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes sense, because null is an absence of a value.

I'd write it like this (assuming the missing part of your query isn't material to your question):

```sql
SELECT 
  c.ID
, c.Email
, c.FirstName
, c.LastName
from Contact_Salesforce c
INNER JOIN Account_Salesforce a ON a.Id = c.AccountId
where 
a.Type is null 
or a.Type not in ('Intern', 'Contractor', 'School Intern', 'Internal User')
```

I'd explicitly make it an INNER JOIN, since that's the default if you don't specify it.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the tips... Is this the expected behavior? I would have assumed NULL would still be queried if its not included in the `a.Type not in` line. As we're effectively saying give me back all records dont DONT it this criteria.. NULL should still be considered.

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky. I've been burned by this a few times and have tried to get in the habit of specifying null conditions separately.

Comment: @deploymentfailure I wrote an article that goes into it if you want more info https://gortonington.com/sfmc-sql-and-the-three-valued-logic-involving-null/